# Mean Value of a Non Linear Function

Tags: statistics, periodic-functions

If I have the following function

$f(x)=1-x^c$ with $x$ being periodic and can be written in the form of $x(t)=Asin(wt)+B$. $c$ is **real** (most of the time not an integer) and $B$ is chosen in a way where $x(t)>0$

Then one can deduce directly that $f(\overline{x}) = \overline{f(x)}$ always if $B=0$ ($\overline{x}$ represents the mean value of x over one period).

**Question** How can I calculate analytically the difference $f(\overline{x}) - \overline{f(x)}$ when $B\neq 0$ ?

Comment: What is the meaning of $x^c$ when $x\lt0$? Note that $x(t)\lt0$ half of the time when $B=0$.

Comment: @Did $B$ is chosen in a way where $x(t)>0$

Comment: What is the meaning of "one can deduce directly that $f(\overline{x}) = \overline{f(x)}$ always if $B=0$"?

Comment: @did it means that the mean value of the function and the function of the mean value of x are the same when $B=0$

Comment: But the function is **undefined** when B=0, see your own first comment.

Comment: True. But if I consider half a period the function is defined, I get the same thing. When I want to consider a whole period, I have to satisfy the condition on $B$